# Youtube in webview shows desktop version of youtube

Tags: java, android, webview

I was making app of my youtube channel but when i run the app i displays desktop version of youtube. But when i put url of some website like my blogger https://atifsoftwares.blogspot.com it displays mobile version.
How can i solve this problem?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Blogger URL screenshot]

Another screenshot of the Youtube channel:

[image: Youtube channel url screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
package com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.theurduteacher;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollViewCallbacks;
import com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableWebView;
import com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ScrollState;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import io.github.kobakei.materialfabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //private String current_page_url ="https://atifsoftwares.blogspot.com/";
    private String current_page_url ="https://www.youtube.com/c/MohammadAtif1";
    private ObservableWebView mWebView;
    private ProgressBar mPrgrsBar;
    private FrameLayout mFrmLayout;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;

    //for bookmarks
    public static final String PREFERENCES = "PREFERENCES_NAME";
    public static final String WEB_LINKS = "links";
    public static final String WEB_TITLE = "title";

    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        //permission for Write_External_storage for downloading
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                Log.d("permission", "permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it");
                String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                requestPermissions(permissions, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        }

        //get url from bookmark(when a url from bookmark activity is clicked)
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            current_page_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        }

        //horizontal progressbar
        mFrmLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        mPrgrsBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mPrgrsBar.setMax(100);

        //implementing WebView
        mWebView = (ObservableWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelpClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress){
                mFrmLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mPrgrsBar.setProgress(progress);
                setTitle("Loading...");
                if (progress==100){
                    mFrmLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    setTitle(view.getTitle());
                }
                super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);
            }
        });
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0");
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

        //Show/Hide ActionBar & Statusbar while scrolling
        mWebView.setScrollViewCallbacks(new ObservableScrollViewCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean firstScroll, boolean dragging) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onDownMotionEvent() {

            }
            @Override
            public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {
                if (scrollState == ScrollState.UP) {
                    actionBar.hide();
                    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                } else if (scrollState == ScrollState.DOWN) {
                    actionBar.show();
                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                }
            }
        });

        //for downloading image onLongClick
        registerForContextMenu(mWebView);

        //check internet connection
        if(haveNetworkConnection()){
            mWebView.loadUrl(current_page_url);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error! Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mWebView.loadUrl(current_page_url);
        }
        mPrgrsBar.setProgress(0);

        //fav menu for copy/share link of opened page
        FabSpeedDial mFabMenu = (FabSpeedDial)findViewById(R.id.fabMenus);
        mFabMenu.addOnMenuItemClickListener(new FabSpeedDial.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuItemClick(FloatingActionButton fab, TextView textView, int itemId) {
                if (itemId==R.id.copyIt){
                    String s = mWebView.getUrl();
                    ClipboardManager cb = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    cb.setText(s);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Link Copied...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (itemId==R.id.shareIt){
                    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    String shareBody = mWebView.getUrl();
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
                }
            }
        });
        //handle downloading
        mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                                url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mWebView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mWebView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mWebView.destroy();
        mWebView = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(contextMenu, view, contextMenuInfo);

        final WebView.HitTestResult webViewHitTestResult = mWebView.getHitTestResult();

        if (webViewHitTestResult.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE ||
                webViewHitTestResult.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE) {

            contextMenu.setHeaderTitle("Download");
            contextMenu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_downimg);
            contextMenu.add(0, 1, 0, "Save - Download Image")
                    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                            String DownloadImageURL = webViewHitTestResult.getExtra();

                            if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(DownloadImageURL)){

                                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(DownloadImageURL));
                                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Downloading Image....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sorry.. Something Went Wrong.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String links = sharedPreferences.getString(WEB_LINKS, null);
        if (links != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ArrayList<String> linkList = gson.fromJson(links, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType());
            if (linkList.contains(current_page_url)) {
                menu.getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_booked);
            } else {
                menu.getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_book);
            }
        } else {
            menu.getItem(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_book);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_bookmark) {
            addRemoveBookmark();
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        if (id == R.id.refresh) {
            if(haveNetworkConnection()){
                mWebView.reload();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error! Check Internet Connection...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mWebView.reload();
            }
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_bookmarkshow){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, BookmarksActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.act_about) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }

    private void addRemoveBookmark() {
        String message;

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String jsonLink = sharedPreferences.getString(WEB_LINKS, null);
        String jsonTitle = sharedPreferences.getString(WEB_TITLE, null);

        if (jsonLink != null && jsonTitle != null) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ArrayList<String> linkList = gson.fromJson(jsonLink, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType());

            ArrayList<String> titleList = gson.fromJson(jsonTitle, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType());

            if (linkList.contains(current_page_url)) {
                linkList.remove(current_page_url);
                titleList.remove(mWebView.getTitle().trim());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(WEB_LINKS, new Gson().toJson(linkList));
                editor.putString(WEB_TITLE, new Gson().toJson(titleList));
                editor.apply();

                message = "Bookmark Removed";

            } else {
                linkList.add(current_page_url);
                titleList.add(mWebView.getTitle().trim());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(WEB_LINKS, new Gson().toJson(linkList));
                editor.putString(WEB_TITLE, new Gson().toJson(titleList));
                editor.apply();

                message = "Bookmarked";
            }
        } else {

            ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
            linkList.add(current_page_url);
            titleList.add(mWebView.getTitle());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(WEB_LINKS, new Gson().toJson(linkList));
            editor.putString(WEB_TITLE, new Gson().toJson(titleList));
            editor.apply();

            message = "Bookmarked";
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private class HelpClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            current_page_url = url;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            mFrmLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                mWebView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong!\nCheck internet connection...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not request for mobile version to do that you must

Change

`https://www.youtube.com/c/MohammadAtif1`

To

```
https://m.youtube.com/c/MohammadAtif1
```

And add below line

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
```

Comment: I tried this, it loads nothing, just a blank page. If i remove www from url then it still loads desktop version

Comment: The url https://m.youtube.com/c/MohammadAtif1 also loading desktop version